# How to convert double to time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, double, type-conversion

I have a variable that stores the time in entered by a user. I get an error that says it cannot convert it from a double to a date. How do I go about doing this?

Essentially I need to take the time in from a user and convert it into minutes. I'm not sure how to do this though.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtTimeIn.TextChanged, txtTimeIn.TextChanged

    Dim m_decTimeIn As DateTime


    m_decTimeIn = Val(txtTimeIn)

End Sub
```

Comment: Dont use Val. Ever.  There are a whole legion of better equipped versions in NET (COnvert.ToDate, DateTime.Parse, TryParse...)

Comment: That's the way I was taught. I don't know any other way

Comment: Now you do - I just gave you 3.  `Val` will cause you loads of problems in the long run - it is *not* the same `Val` as in QuickBasic or VisualBasic 3-6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim myDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(myDouble)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Val` function converts, in this particular overload, a `String` value to a `Double`.  This type is not convertible to `DateTime` and hence the compiler issues an error.

In order to convert a `String` to a date use `Datetime.Parse` instead

```
m_decTimeIn = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeIn.Text)
```

Comment: If I change it to that it gives me an error saying that "value of type  systems.windows.forms.TextBox cannot be converted to type string".

Comment: Ah I see, I actually should have seen that myself. Cheers!

Comment: Actually, how is a date time stored exactly. I need to convert it into minutes for my next part of the program. Is it stored so that the user enters it as HH:MM:SS, if so, how do I convert that to minutes?

Comment: @user3275784 Use the `Minutes` property on the `DateTime` object

Comment: so something like this `m_decTimeIn = m_decTimeIn.Minute` ?

I just an error if I do that

Comment: @user3275784 actually I'm gussing that you get `can't convert Integer to DateTime` or something along those lines.  The type of `Minute` is `Integer` hence it can't be assigned to `DateTime`

Comment: Yeah that's the error I get. So do I need to convert `DateTime` to an integer first, then convert it to minutes?

Comment: @user3275784 you're going to have to use a different variable for each step because they are different types

Comment: So I'll keep my initial variable `m_decTimeIn` as a `DateTime`. Then make another one like `TimeInINT` and convert it from `DateTime` to Integer. Then `TimeInMins` from and Integer to minutes.